# How to replace all array values with one character in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have this array: `$array = ['1', '2', '3'];`

I would like to replace all values in that array with asterisk sign `*`.
Essentially, I want to get array like this: `$new = ['*', '*', '*'];`.

What is the best way to do this ? I am hoping that there is some short simple solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `array_fill()` @ http://php.net

Comment: Seems a bit pointless to me, but `array_walk($array, function(&$value) { $value = '*'; });`

Comment: But why not simply create an array of the same size using `$new = array_fill(0, count($array), '*');`

Comment: I like this. But is it better than using array_map ?

Comment: @MarkBaker - curious about why you're using &$value instead of $value.  Doesn't php pass by reference?

Comment: @devlincarnate - Objects are pass by "pointer"; but scalars are always "pass by value", unless you specifically indicate "pass by reference" using `&` as described in the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = ['1', '2', '3'];
$newarray = array_map(function($val) { return "*"; }, $array);
?>
```

Comment: Still seems overkill compared to the `array_fill(0, count($array), '*');` solution ;-)